# Secured upload to S3 from mobile applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mobile

I have an IOS and Android application. Each app uploads a few files one by one to AWS S3. Is there a secure way to do this, without supplying the AWS credentials? I don't want that the app will have access to such a sensitive and always valid information.

The closest solution I have found so far is the preSignURL which is generated by my server and valid for temporary time. The biggest problem is that it is valid only for one specific file. I need a URL that will be valid for temporary time and for many files.

I also found the POST solution:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

But in this case, they hard code the AWS credentials which are very problematic for me.

Is there any solution in which my server can supply some temporary link for upload any file the application will want? Something like PreSignURL but without the name limitation?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try to upload files from your server instead of uploading directly from the App?

Comment: Can you provide additional information, like who will be the user of the app, which mechanism do you plan to authenticate the user/the app against any backend service (you are mentioning a server)?

Comment: I planning to make communication with server in the future with the access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a small research for you and the best solution in my opinion is to create a temporary AWS credentials. You recreate every 1 hour new temp credentials that will be valid for 2 hours or something like that.

```
    private Credentials GenerateTempCredentials()
    {         
        AssumeRoleRequest _assumeRoleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest
        {
            DurationSeconds = 3600,
            RoleSessionName = "MySession",
            RoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:role/RoleName"
        };
        AssumeRoleResponse res = _sts_client.AssumeRole(_assumeRoleRequest);                  
        Credentials cred = res.Credentials;                    
        return cred;                   
    }

    public Credentials GetTempCredentials()
    {
        return _credentials;
    }
```

When you create the AWS user, make sure to set its policty according to you needs.